# JTabbedPane action performed

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Im looking for way where an action can be performed while using a tabbed pane whenever new tab is opened.

Something like `formwindowopenned`

Answer (score 2):

> Im looking for way where an action can be performed while using a tabbed pane whenever new tab is opened.

I assume you mean when a user clicks on an existing tab to switch to that tab. If so, then you can add a `ChangeListener` to the tabbedPane and listen for the `stateChanged` event.

If you are talking about adding a new tab to the tabbed pane, then you would just manage that in your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

**All actions on tabs** (this will get you extra actions, not only mouse clicks, for example, if you change tab by code using selected index, this code will be executed):

```
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
    JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) changeEvent.getSource();
    int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    System.out.println("Tab changed to: " + sourceTabbedPane.getTitleAt(index));
  }
};
myJTabbedPanel.addChangeListener(changeListener);
```

**Only mouse clicks** on tabs:

```
/** 
 * Detects clicks when user click tab inside tabbed pane 
 */ 
private void addMouseEventToPanel(){ 
  this.myJTabbedPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() 
  { 

    @Override 
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      System.out.println("You clicked on tab number "+this.myJTabbedPanel.getSelectedIndex()); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

  });
}
```

Comment: Tabs can be activated in other ways then just using the mouse

Comment: Modified for all actions too :D